# Find first index of a string after index

Tags: javascript

I have a string: "www.google.com.sdg.jfh.sd"

I want to find the first ".s" string that is found after "sdg".

so I have the index of "sdg", by:

```
var start_index = str.indexOf("sdg");
```

now I need to find the first ".s" index that is found after "sdg"

any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by _"find the first .s index"?_ You want to find its position in the string?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This code might be helpful

```
var string = "www.google.com.sdg.jfh.sd",
  preString = "sdg",
  searchString = ".s",
  preIndex = string.indexOf(preString),
  searchIndex = preIndex + string.substring(preIndex).indexOf(searchString);
```

You can test it **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ngD4y/3/)**

Comment: This concept is perfect when using regex for getting the index. `indexOf(string)`, the next answer is obviously better, but in case of `new RegExp(searchString, "g").exec(text).index`, this is awesome. :-)

Comment: Fails when var string = "www.s.g.soogle.com.sdg.jfh.sd";

Answer (score 151):

There's a second parameter which controls the starting position of search:

```
String.prototype.indexOf(arg, startPosition);
```

So you can do

```
str.indexOf('s', start_index);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "www.google.com.sdg.jfh.sd";
var search = "sdg";
var start_index = str.substring(str.indexOf(search) + search.length).indexOf(".s");
```